# signal r server method is not invoking

Tags: c#, signalr, console-application

I have created SignalR functionalities in a console application. I am able to invoke a server function from client, but when I am trying to send a message from the server to the client, the sever console is closing.

Below is my code:

**Sever Code**

Below code used in Hub inherited class

```
[HubName("TestHub")]
public class TestHub: Hub
{
    public void NotifyAllClients()
    {
        Clients.Caller.notify();
    }
}
```

Startup Class

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ConsoleApp1.Startup))]
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
    using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Client Code

```
IHubProxy _hub;
string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
 var connection = new HubConnection(url);
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
connection.Start();
_hub.On("notify", () => Console.WriteLine("Notified!"));
```

Comment: The method of the Hub has not any parameters. How are you going to send message?

Comment: Without parameter i am trying to call the function.

Comment: _hub.On("notify", () => Console.WriteLine("Notified!")); this is the code